# The Worst Afternoon

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, steganography

> Was worried about this trip for days -- couldn't take the car -- terrible traffic all the way there -- a gang of jerks blocking my way and the bus had just left -- tried to run and maybe sprained my ACL -- in tons of pain and obviously missed the bus -- hurting and ready to sob -- am annoyed and just want to curl up with some hot _____ .

**What could I want to drink?**

<sup>EDIT: Tags added post-solve.  Great work @Stiv!</sup>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Right now, you'd really appreciate some:

> **RUM PUNCH**

Why? Well, notice that the story conceals:

> The surnames of successive US Presidents:
>
>  Was worried about this trip **FOR D**ays - couldn't take the **CAR - TER**rible traffic all the way the**RE - A GAN**g of jerks blocking my way and the **BUS H**ad just left - tried to run and maybe sprained my A**CL - IN TON**s of pain and obviously missed the **BUS - H**urting and ready to s**OB - AM A**nnoyed and just want to curl up with some hot _____ .

The solution therefore requires us to:

> Make use of the name of the *next* successive US President, *Trump*. How? Well, the last letter of hot is 'T' - we need to follow this with something beginning 'RUMP', hence **RUM PUNCH**.

The title provides an extra clue:

> It conceals the name of *another* US President: *The Wors**T AFT**ernoon*.

Comment: Exactly right! Perfect explanation. Check coming soon.